# How to get list selector for whole list item?

Tags: android

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal">                                   
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="97dip"
    android:layout_height="110dip"
    android:paddingLeft="2dip"
    android:paddingRight="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="7dip"
    android:paddingBottom="7dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
/>
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"    
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"

        />

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dip"
      />

</LinearLayout>
```

am getting selection only for image its not selecting the whole listitem?how to fix it?

Comment: plz add your code of adapter for listview..

Comment: if i am using relative layout its not taking second textview below first both occur in same position even i am giving different position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn how to declare layouts : [Declaring Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)